# What does ゆいって mean?

Tags: translation, colloquial-language

振り返ってみると、ゆいって今まで何の部活もやってこなかったもんねー。

I can't find the meaning in dictionaries..

Comment: ゆい is a name of someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ゆい is a girl's first name. Yui.

って is a colloquial topic marker similar to は.
It's the subject of a question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15004/difference-between-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-and-%E3%81%AF-as-topic-marker) if you wanna read more about it.

> 振り返ってみると、ゆいって今まで何の部活もやってこなかったもんねー。
>   Looking back on it, Yui (or "you" if the listener is Yui) didn't do any after school clubs up until now, did she (you).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this sentence was obtained from a K-On! episode on purpose, but I wanted to provide some context.

Since this sentence appears in the beginning of Episode 1, we can safely say that the conversation is between Nodoka and Yui, who are discussing how late it is already and yet Yui hasn't picked a school club:

> 和{のどか}：　はああ、こうやってニートが出来上がっていくのねー。
>
> Sigh... you're going to be a NEET.
>
> **唯{ゆい}**：　はっ！　部活やってないだけでニート！？
>
> What! I'm going to be a NEET just because I'm not in a club!?
>
> 和：　振り返ってみると、**ゆいって**今まで何の部活もやってこなかったもんねー。
>
> Looking back, you've never been in a club.
>
> (English translations modified from subtitles in the link below.)

As you can see above, ゆい is the bolded name. As for って、@Ash seems to have it covered.

The dialogue starts at around 04:15 here:
https://kissanime.to/Anime/K-On/Episode-001?id=26500

The transcript can be found here:
http://animetranscripts.wikispaces.com/K-ON!+%28Japanese%29+%3E+01.+%E5%BB%83%E9%83%A8%EF%BC%81

Comment: Thanks, Yes this is from k-on, I'm trying to read and look up each word and since there's no spacing, I often confuse that it's a word, and see it doesn't come up in dictionaries.