# What does する in its lone て-form mean?

Tags: translation, て-form

The sentence

> トムが殺人事件を**目撃したって**、本当なの？

translates to

> Is it true Tom witnessed a murder?

**Question:** I am confused about 目撃+したって, which I assume translates to something like "doing-witnessing".  **Specifically, why is する in its lone て-form here, without any connecting verb?** Before this, I thought lone て-forms were considered ungrammatical.

Comment: ?? The て form of する is して

Comment: And what do you mean by "lone て-form"?

Comment: It seems the question was based on at least one misconception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between って and は as topic marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15004/difference-between-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6-and-%e3%81%af-as-topic-marker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of this って  here as a shortening of っていうのは or というのは. 目撃する is what's called a サ変 verb, where you take a noun and add する to make a verb out of it. 'Is it true Tom witness a murder?' is a perfect translation already.

Forget trying to do 'hyper-literal' translations under the mistaken assumption it will help you grasp the internal logic of the Japanese sentence. 目撃する is one unit, closer to 'witness' than 'do witness'; you can't say 目撃をする.

As for って here, basically, it explicitly marks it as hearsay. The most literal I believe there's any point in going, 'How they say Tom witnessed a murder, is it true?'

Comment: Is there a more literal translation of the sentence that you can think of (something like "Tom murder-case did-witness, is that a fact?"), because I'm still having trouble understanding exactly what って is doing. The dictionary definitions of this word I can find don't seem to make sense in this context, and the definitions of っていう and というのは also don't seem to make sense to me in this sentence either. I appreciate your help!

Comment: って marking what came before it as hearsay suddenly makes the sentence understandable (and also distinguishes it from what the sentence would connote without the って)!  I like "I hear that Tom did-witness a murder-case, is that so?" as a literal translation, but the non-literal "Is it true Tom witnessed a murder?" is of course more English idiomatic :)

I might be odd, but I find that literal translations make Japanese suddenly understandable to me, and that non-literal translations make the language feel like everything is some special case/disconnected idiom that you just have to memorize.